# I'm not getting matches on my multiValued fields

Tags: solr, multivalue, edismax, dismax

I'm not getting matches when using edismax defType and multiValued fields.

```
<requestHandler name="/search" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="rows">20</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    <str name="qf">
      title^1.8
    </str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and the schema.xml definitions.

```
<types>
  <fieldtype name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<fields>
  <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

When I check the docs, a perfectly matching doc is returned.

```
"docs": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": [
       "logo"
     ],
     "_version_": 1465224933480071200,
     "score": 1
  },..
```

But when I execute the following query, numFound is 0.

```
/solr/core1/search?q=logo&wt=json&indent=true
```

This does not happen with multiValued="false" fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried: `/solr/core1/search?q=title:logo&wt=json&indent=true`? That was one error in my case.